# CheckboxListTile not working while working with real time database from firebase

Tags: dart, flutter

I'm trying to create a List of data from online server Firebase using StreamBuilder bu the checkbox won't get checked.

I have used StreamBuilder to get the data and used LisTile widget to build the list items but the checkboxtilelist widget won't work after defining setState() function. And buildBody is defined under build Widget class.

```
Widget buildBody(BuildContext context) {
  return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
    stream: Firestore.instance.collection('hisab').snapshots(),
    builder: (context, snapshots) {
      if (!snapshots.hasData) {
        return LinearProgressIndicator();
      }
      return _buildList(context, snapshots.data.documents);
    }
  );
}

Widget _buildList(BuildContext context, List<DocumentSnapshot> snapshot) {
  return ListView(
    padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
    children: snapshot.map((data) => _buildListitem(context, data)).toList(),
  );
}

Widget _buildListitem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot data) {
  final record = Record.fromSnapshot((data));
  bool _values = false;
  void _onChanged(bool newValue) {
    setState(() {
      _values = newValue;
    });
  }

  return Padding(
    padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0, vertical: 9.0),
    child: Container(
      decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
      ),
      child: new ListTile(
        onTap: () {
          _onChanged(!_values);
        },
        leading: CircleAvatar(child: Text(record.name[0])),
        title: new Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            new CheckboxListTile(
              title: Text(record.name),
              value: _values,
              onChanged: _onChanged,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's good idea if you create new stateful widget class:

```
class CustomListItemWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  CustomListItemWidget({Key key, @required this.record}) : super(key: key);

  final record;

  @override
  State createState() => _CustomListItemWidgetState();
}

class _CustomListItemWidgetState extends State<CustomListItemWidget> {

  bool _values = false;
  void _onChanged(bool newValue) {
    setState(() {
      _values = newValue;
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 18.0, vertical: 9.0),
      child: Container(
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(color: Colors.white),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5.0),
        ),
        child: new ListTile(
          onTap: () {
            _onChanged(!_values);
          },
          leading: CircleAvatar(child: Text(widget.record.name[0])),
          title: new Column(
            children: <Widget>[
              new CheckboxListTile(
                title: Text(widget.record.name[0]),
                value: _values,
                onChanged: _onChanged,
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Next, you can pass value from your method _buildListitem:

```
Widget _buildListitem(BuildContext context, DocumentSnapshot data) {
  return CustomListItemWidget(
    record: Record.fromSnapshot((data)),
  );
}
```

Comment: That was really helpful. Appreciate the help. I knew what I had to do, I did even think of using initState().